# Raising an exception with pyo3

Tags: rust, pyo3

How do I correctly raise an Exception?

I've tried the following:

```
#[pymethods]
impl Foo {
    #[new]
    fn __new__(arg1: u8, ...) -> Self {
        if arg1 > LIMIT {
            let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
            let py = gil.python();
            PyErr::new::<exceptions::ValueError, _>("Parameter arg1 has invalid value").restore(py);
        }
        Foo {...}
    }
```

This is exactly the same implementation as how it is described [here](https://pyo3.rs/v0.11.1/exception.html).

When I create an instance of `Foo` with an invalid parameter value then instead of a `ValueError` a `SystemError` is raised with error text `<class 'Foo'> returned a result with an error set`.

I'm using pyo3 0.11.1 and Rust 1.47.0 nightly on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `PyResult` that returns an exception (which will be raised in python):

```rust
#[pymethods]
impl Foo {
    #[new]
    fn __new__(arg1: u8, ...) -> PyResult<Self> {
        if arg1 > LIMIT {
            Err(exceptions::PyValueError::new_err("Parameter arg1 has invalid value"))
        } else {
            Ok(Foo {...})
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks! It works! Didn't know that I can return a PyResult in the __new__ method.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the example you link to is about error management in main.

Here I believe that, as the `SystemError` indicates, you're simultanously setting an error and *returning a value*. Since these are obviously exclusive conditions (it makes no sense to raise *and* return), the Python interpreter faults.

As [documented for ctors](https://pyo3.rs/v0.11.1/class.html#return-type) as well as noted after the first snippet of [raising an exception](https://pyo3.rs/v0.11.1/exception.html#raising-an-exception), you should return a `[Py]Result`, with the `Err` case signaling an error which pyo3 will set for the interpreter.