Return a custom error including payload in PyO3
All examples of returning errors in PyO3 contain only simple strings. However, I often want to return errors with a payload, usually the bad element and its location. How do I return a custom error with payload in PyO3?
For example, something like this in Python:
@dataclass
class NotIntError(Exception):
    item: object

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Expected int but found {type(self.item)}: {self.item}"

def validate_int(item):
    if not isinstance(a, int):
        raise NotIntError(item)

I am pretty sure this is way far off but because SO people like to see an attempt, here it goes:
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::PyInt;

#[pyclass]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NotIntError {
    item: Py<PyAny>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl NotIntError {
    fn __str__(&self) -> PyResult<String> {
        Ok(format!(
            "Expected int but found {:?}: {:?}",
            self.item.get_type().name(),
            self.item
        ))
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
pub fn validate_int(item: &Bound<'_, PyAny>) -> PyResult<()> {
    if !item.is_instance_of::<PyInt>() {
        let error = NotIntError { item: item.into() };
        Err(PyErr::new::<NotIntError, _>(error))
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}


Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63128052/raising-an-exception-with-pyo3

@realhuman No, I know how to return PyResult in order to raise an exception from PyO3. I just don't know how to give that exception any attributes.

Ok so I did a bit of research, apparently there's an open Github Issue on this topic so unfortunately I don't think this is possible currently... https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues/295

The tricky part of this is noting that pyclass normally implements the IntoPyObject trait, which you need in order to return anything back to Python. However, pyclass doesn't do this when the class extends anything, like you have to do for an exception. Also, the derive macro for IntoPyObject only returns a dict, not an instance of the class, so that is not useful here.
The hard work comes in implementing IntoPyObject for pyclasses that subclass a Python builtin (like any of the exceptions).
Once that's in place, you just have to learn how to use the Python object to implement __str__.
Also, you will have a much better time constructing the PyErr yourself rather than relying on the too-clever PyErrArguments mechanic that PyErr::new relies on. Use PyErr::from_value instead.
use pyo3::exceptions::PyTypeError;
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::PyInt;

#[pyclass(frozen, extends=PyTypeError)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NotIntError {
    item: PyObject,
}

impl<'py> IntoPyObject<'py> for NotIntError {
    type Target = PyAny;
    type Output = Bound<'py, Self::Target>;
    type Error = PyErr;

    fn into_pyobject(self, py: Python<'py>) -> Result<Self::Output, Self::Error> {
        py.get_type::<NotIntError>().call1((self.item,))
    }
}

#[pymethods]
impl NotIntError {
    #[new]
    fn new(item: Bound<'_, PyAny>) -> NotIntError {
        NotIntError {
            item: item.unbind(),
        }
    }

    fn __str__(&self, py: Python) -> PyResult<String> {
        let item_type = self.item.bind(py).get_type().name().unwrap();
        Ok(format!(
            "Expected int but found {}: {}",
            item_type, self.item
        ))
    }
}

#[pyfunction]
pub fn validate_int(item: &Bound<'_, PyAny>) -> PyResult<()> {
    if !item.is_instance_of::<PyInt>() {
        let py = item.py();
        let error = NotIntError {
            item: item.to_owned().into(),
        };
        Err(PyErr::from_value(error.into_pyobject(py)?))
    } else {
        Ok(())
    }
}

I welcome suggestions. I'll continue to make improvements as I test this solution on real code.
